# Jquery copy input value to other forms

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a js fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/h971gu5f/3/

```
    <form action="" class="form">
        <label for="">Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="number"/>
    </form>

    <form action="" class="form">
        <label for="">Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="number"/>
    </form>

    <form action="" class="form">
        <label for="">Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="number"/>
    </form>
```

I have a number of forms on a page.

The forms will enable people to sign up to different events.

If they sign up to more than one event, the information will be the same in each form.

If they start typing in one form is it possible the to replicate the input in the other forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this, just add respective classes to inputs.

```
$(function(){
    $('input.myClass').keyup(function(){
        $('input.otherInputClass').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

jQuery required

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.number').on('keyup', function(){
        $(this).parent().siblings().find('input.number').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h971gu5f/4/

Answer (score 0):

As the input value should be the same for all inputs, it's not necessary to exclude the current input from setting the value (though it's not necessary to update the current value with itself), so it's also possible to simplify it to

```
$("input").on("keyup", function () {
   $("input").val($(this).val());
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h971gu5f/6/)